# HTTP Proxy only - now sites over HTTPS not working

Tags: networking, proxy, https

My company only has a http proxy. Sites over non-SSL http work fine. However a site like `https://google.com` is not working. What must I do to force https to use my company's http proxy?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're getting the error "Your connection is not secure", it appears that your company's network is launching a [man-in-the-middle attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) to try to break all of your secure connections. You'll have to ask your IT department why they're doing this. Note that their "fix" will likely be to install their own root certificate on your computer, which will make the errors you see go away, but won't actually make your connections secure (as they'll then be able to decrypt them with their root certificate).